# How do I stop needing to cache:clear every annotation change?

Tags: doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, symfony5, symfony5.4

I have a fresh project from built in ***Symfony 5*** and have ***Api Platform 2.7***.
My project also have ***PHP 7.4***.

My problem is that every change that I got in annotations, I need to input ***cache:clear*** or ***cache:pool:clear*** to see my changes i.e (Adding serialization groups, adding attributes to @ApiResource annotation etc.).

I've just seen in the Symfonycasts tutorial that Ryan has continuous development without clearing the cache every change, looked into conversations about the cache, but nothing helped. Conversation told me that to see changes, they clear the cache, but I don't want to do that every change.

My project is still not in PHP 8, so I am still using annotations for Api Platform, but I wonder if that will all be fixed if I am using the new attributes.

This is the result of my default framework cache when I enter ***bin/console debug:config framework cache***

```
Current configuration for "framework.cache"
===========================================

prefix_seed: _/Users/mjmconvento/Projects/fresh_project.App_KernelDevDebugContainer
app: cache.adapter.filesystem
system: cache.adapter.system
directory: /Users/mjmconvento/Projects/fresh_project/var/cache/dev/pools/app
default_redis_provider: 'redis://localhost'
default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost'
default_doctrine_dbal_provider: database_connection
default_pdo_provider: database_connection
pools: {  }
```

I also dumped my my ***$_ENV***, and this is my result, I was sure I am in dev.

```
array:8 [▼
  "APP_ENV" => "dev"
  "APP_SECRET" => "833e6f898ca3dcacfd93c3a22b7609b4"
  "DATABASE_URL" => "mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/test_db?serverVersion=8&charset=utf8mb4"
  "MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN" => "doctrine://default?auto_setup=0"
  "CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN" => "^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$"
  "SYMFONY_DOTENV_VARS" => "APP_ENV,APP_SECRET,DATABASE_URL,MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN,CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN"
  "APP_DEBUG" => "1"
  "SHELL_VERBOSITY" => 3
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more of Api Platform issue.

In config, I've added this `metadata_backward_compatibility_layer: false` to `config/packages/api_platform.yml`

The default value is true. Then after changing, I don't need to refresh every change.

The label in `config:dump-reference api_platform` doesn't state any of this behavior, or I just missed it.

This is the label:

```
# If true, declared services are using legacy interfaces for the following services: "api_platform.iri_converter", "api_platform.openapi.factory", "api_platform.identifiers_extractor".
    metadata_backward_compatibility_layer: true
```

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. I appreciate your sharing